# Jay Garrick's helmet timing discrepancy?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In Flash Season 2 - during Jay Garrick Vs Zoom

We see that Jay's helmet got sucked into the black hole, (which was opened way after the closure of Speedforce hole and Barry returned from past)

[image: Jay Garrick Helmet getting sucked into BlackHole]

But during finale of Flash Season 1, the cap enters the Earth 1 from the wormhole barry opens using the Speedforce (the hole through which Barry went into the past)

[image: Jay Garrick Cap comes out from Wormhole?]

Is this a plot mistake? or something that I am missing?

Comment: Since it's a **time** wormhole Im not sure that any explanation is really possible. Time works differently inside one I'd guess.

Comment: Plus, of course, Garrick **is** Zoom so he's **probably lying**